# Connecting as SYS to an Oracle Database from PHP OCI8

Tags: php, database, oracle11g, wampserver, oci8

I'm trying to access the ORACLE database from PHP, i'm using WampServer Version 2.2
Apache 2.4.2 – PHP 5.4.3 and oracle 11g. I tried many ways including :

```
<?php

if ($conn = oci_connect('sys as sysdba', '12345', '//localhost/orcl'))
{
    print 'Successfully connected to Oracle Database!';     
}
else
{
     $errmsg = oci_error();
     print 'Oracle connection failed' . $errmsg['message'];
}
?>
```

i get the following error every time i execute:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function OCILogon() in C:\wamp\www\IDS\Index.php on line 3
```

Does anyone know how to solve this ??

Comment: Did you google? https://forums.oracle.com/thread/332514

Comment: i did that but i didn't get any good answer .... i'll check the link :)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to remove the `";"` semicolon from the `php.ini` file at the oci8 line

it was like this:

```
;extension=php_oci8.dll
```

i changed it to:

```
extension=php_oci8.dll
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct connect string would look like 
`$conn = oci_connect('sys', '12345', '//localhost/orcl', null, OCI_SYSDBA))`

Make sure you have 
`oci8.privileged_connect = on`
in your `php.ini` in order to enable privileged connections. Look out for this parameter in the [OCI8] section of your php.ini.